# Discrete Random Variable Probabilities?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, means

I have the following discrete random variable $\mathbb{X}$ over $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ with the pmf:

$f_{\mathbb{X}}(1) = P(\mathbb{X} = 1) = 0.25$

$f_{\mathbb{X}}(2) = P(\mathbb{X} = 2) = 0.4$

$f_{\mathbb{X}}(3) = P(\mathbb{X} = 3) = 0.1$

$f_{\mathbb{X}}(4) = P(\mathbb{X} = 4) = 0.15$

$f_{\mathbb{X}}(5) = P(\mathbb{X} = 5) = 0.1$

and I want to find $P(\mathbb{X} = \mu)$

I can easily find $\mu$ as follows:

$$\mu = \sum_{i = 1}^5 xf_{\mathbb{X}}(x) = 1(0.25)+2(0.4)+3(0.1)+4(0.15)+5(0.1) = 2.45$$

but, how do you find $P(\mathbb{X} = 2.45)$?

Do I simply round down since $\mathbb{X}$ is discrete? Do I interpolate? Any clarification would be great!

Comment: $2.45$ is not a member of $\Omega$, so the probability is obviously zero. The answer you accepted is misleading.

Comment: @StubbornAtom thank you for the clarification, I figured there was something specific I was missing regarding $P(\mathbb{X} = \mu)$ and discrete random variables

Answer (score -2):

You need to assume a functional form for the distribution:

[image]

A simple quadratic fit gives:  $f(X) = 0.34 - 0.0335714 x - 0.00357143 x^2$
and then $f(2.45) = 0.236313$.

Comment: so you should interpolate even though $\mathbb{X}$ can only take on discrete values?

Comment: Yes... so long as your goal is to compute the distribution at a non-integer value (2.45).

Comment: Sorry but this does not make sense in this context.